# How to set a Timeout when using the PCL version of DataServiceContext?

Tags: c#, xamarin, odata, portable-class-library

I am using BingSearchContainer to search for images on the web. I would like to set a Timeout as we are using it from a mobile device and it is quite likely that the network will disappear.

BingSearchContainer is a thin class that derives most of its functionality from its base class **System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext**.

The standard net40 version of this class has a Timeout property which would look to do the job. We however are using the *portable-net45+wp8+win8+wpa* version though which does not have this property. This can be seen from the source [here](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/blob/master/src/Microsoft.OData.Client/DataServiceContext.cs)

On line 470, where it says:

```
#if !ASTORIA_LIGHT  && !PORTABLELIB // Timeout not available
```

Does anybody know of a different technique for setting the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is other way to set HTTP request timeout as long as you are using this client. It encapsulates HTTP communication and the only way to access lower level details is via its properties.

It's strange why request timeout is not enabled in PCL version since PCL versions of HttpClient (and other OData PCL libraries) have it.